# Thunderbird keeps popping up the "Add a new address book" window

Tags: 20.04, thunderbird, window, address-book

Since a week or so, Thunderbird (68.10.0, 64 bit, running on vanilla Ubuntu 20.04) keeps popping up prompts to "Add a new address book" every 10 minutes or so.

The window looks like this:[image: Thunderbird popup]

I've restarted Thunderbird, restarted my laptop... To no avail - the popups keep coming.

How do I debug this?

Comment: Did you try creating the adresbook? Probably one is missing or has an issue.

Comment: Thanks, @vanadium, that seems to have done the trick... I feel pretty silly now for not having tried this myself :-|

Answer (score 1):

Per the brilliant hint of @vanadium, simply clicking 'Next' and creating the address book stopped the popups from appearing. Probably this was some kind of update/config/setting mishap, guess we'll never know.